# How / Should I flag questions where the error is on a remote system the user doesn't have access to?

Tags: discussion, flags

Question in question: [SOAP function giving me a 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127538/soap-function-giving-me-a-500-error)

It looks like the asker is saying the error is coming from the server as a result of their request. If the request is OK, and the error is being caused by some coding problem on the API server, and the asker doesn't have access to this (which isn't clear in this case, but could be in others), then what is a correct reaction from a moderation point of view?

Should I flag this and if so under what category? I'm not clear on this.

Answer (score 3):

In most such situations the OP won't be able to provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem, so use the close reason applicable for any other question lacking in information (unclear would be fine).

If there is enough information to answer the question (which seems unlikely, but technically possible), but the OP just isn't capable of applying the solution to the problem because the system is out of their control, then just answer the question.  The author will know what the problem is and understand that they can't solve it, and any future readers who might be in a position to actually apply the solution will be able to use it.